# How to use symmetricity of an equality on Coq

Tags: coq

Using coq, I tried these:

```
Lemma eqSym: forall (n m: nat), n = m -> m = n.
Proof.
   intros.
```

But what can I do now? I cannot think of how to prove this.

Comment: You can rewrite using your assumption and your goal then follows by reflexivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tactic called `symmetry` that does precisely this!

But if you find yourself in such a situation, you may `Search` for relevant lemmas already in the library:

```
Search (?a = ?b) (?b = ?a).
```

One of the first results is

```
eq_sym: forall [A : Type] [x y : A], x = y -> y = x
```

which is a general version of your lemma.

Answer (score 0):

Both @ana-borges' and @NaCl's answers are great, and show how you would approach this most practically, but you might also want to know what goes on "under the hood".

You have the information that `n = m`, and it is an inductive proposition of type `eq` [1], which means that you can consider the different ways you could have obtained that information with a `match` statement.  So the complete definition of a term with the desired type (i.e. your lemma) is

```
Definition eqSym: forall (n m: nat), n = m -> m = n  := 
  fun n m H => match H with eq_refl => eq_refl end.
```

[1] You can find out what the syntactic notation really means with `Locate "=".`